# Binding event with mouseover on an iframe that sits on my page with a src that contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some third party iframes that sit on my page and I want to capture when a user `mousesover` them ONLY if the src of those iframes contain either twitter or facebook anywhere in the src text. Since I can't capture the clicks (I can with their custom methods, I want to keep code completely seperate). I want to capture when a user mouses into an iframe (that sits on my page, is not brought in by them). The "SRC" of the iframe is outside my site, but the actually call is in my page. Any ideas?

ala:

```
var _self = this;
$("iframe src").filter('/facebook|twitter/')
    .mouseover(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    _self.somemethodcall();
});
```

or something like:

```
var _self = this;
$('iframe').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src').match(/facebook|twitter/);
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    _self.somemethodcall();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
var a = /facebook|twitter/;

$('iframe').live('mouseover', 
  function () {
      if(a.test($(this).attr('src'))){
             alert('Found it!');
      }
  }  
);​
```

First we throw the Regular Expression in a variable named `a`. Then upon hovering the iframe  we test the `src` of the `iframe` to our Regular Expression, which will return true if the value of `src` contains either `facebook` or `twitter`.

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2PZ2c/
(third one is the one with the google.com source)

**Readables:**

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

**Side note:**

This solution will also work with other handlers like `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, etc.

**Edit**:

I've edited my code to use the .live() function instead. This function will attach an event handler to both current elements as future ones.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2PZ2c/1/

Source: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Will that also work on IFRAMES that are injected "into" my page from third party ".js" calls? In other words, not my iframes - but rather third party ones that are inject via js from their "includes js calls" that might sit on my page?

Comment: Regular mouseover would not, not. But i've updated my code to use the .live() function instead for the reasons explained in my answer.

Comment: Hey Joey - thanks for your responses. I do have two questions. (1.) Should there be an event.stopPropagation() in there? and (2.)  
When you say "regular mouseover would not.." are you suggesting that "there is a way" to detect a mouseover or click in an iframe that is not native to my page but is brought in via a third party include js file?

Comment: James, 1) Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events. 2) Using the .live() method you can attach event handlers to both current and future elements. These future elements can also be brought in via third party js. The .live() method is also the only way to attach handlers to new elements